# short vertical line on axis (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

What's the name of this line (in yellow circle of below picture), and how do I change its line width?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called ticklines. You can find it in this documentation [page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/pyplots/fig_axes_customize_simple.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-fig-axes-customize-simple-py) for details.